# Type of extending classes

Tags: typescript

I would like to type a variable such as its value must be the name of a class extending a base class.

```
class Base {}
class Foo extends Base {}
class Bar extends Base {}

function myFunction(myObject: Base) {
  let objectTypeAsString: string = foo.constructor.name;
}

let foo = new Foo();

myFunction(foo);
```

This code is valid, but *objectTypeAsString* is typed as *string* and I would like to have a more secure type. 
I understand *foo.constructor.name* is obtained at runtime, but maybe there is a more smart way to defined and obtain the class name.

Comment: Not possible currently

Answer (score 1):

Note: I'm going to add properties to empty classes to avoid [weirdness](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-do-these-empty-classes-behave-strangely).

---

This isn't really possible, and the workarounds might be more trouble than they're worth.  It is a [known issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3841) that the `constructor` property of a class instance is not strongly typed in TypeScript.  And the `name` property of the constructor is also just typed as `string`.  So you'd have to try to do these things manually, which is tedious ans doesn't scale...

...and the compiler resists you at every turn.  You apparently can't manually strongly type the `name` property of the static side of a class:

```
class Hmm {
  hmm = 123; 
  static readonly name: "Hmm"; // error!
  //              ~~~~
  // Static property 'name' conflicts with built-in property 
  // 'Function.name' of constructor function 'Hmm'.
}
```

Even if you *could* do that, it would make the compiler very angry when you start extending the class:

```
class Hmm {
  hmm = 123;
  //@ts-ignore
  static readonly name: "Hmm";
}

class Oops extends Hmm // error!
//    ~~~~
// Class static side 'typeof Oops' incorrectly 
// extends base class static side 'typeof Hmm'.
{
  oops = 456;
  //@ts-ignore
  static readonly name: "Oops";
}
```

Because subclasses need to be assignable to superclasses, but `"Oops"` is not assignable to `"Hmm"`.  This means that subclasses will need to be not strictly subclasses, but instead we will need something like [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html).  But you can't use instance generic type parameters in static properties, so we have to forget the static side of the class.

---

One thing we can do is strongly type the `constructor` instance property ourselves, using a [trick](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5989#issuecomment-163066313) which is about to get even more [tricky](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/31119) in TS3.5:

```
// this is now generic
class Base<N extends string = "Base"> {
  ["constructor"]: typeof Base & { name: N }; // strongly type "constructor"
  base = "b"; 
}
class Foo extends Base<"Foo"> {
  foo = "f";
}
class Bar extends Base<"Bar"> {
  bar = "b";
}

// this is now generic too
function myFunction<N extends string>(myObject: Base<N>): N {
  return myObject.constructor.name;
}

let foo = new Foo();

myFunction(foo); // "Foo"
```

That all works as far as it goes, but it's ugly.  So I guess the short answer should be "you can't do this" and the slightly longer answer is "you can kind of sort of do this a little but you shouldn't".

Oh well, hope that's helpful.  Good luck!